# BeautifulSoup (bs4) not getting elements with find_all nor select nor select_one

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

Example Url to be crawled: [www.yelp.com/biz/dallas-marketing-rockstar-dallas?adjust_creative=3cZu3ieq3omptvF-Yfj2ow&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=3cZu3ieq3omptvF-Yfj2ow'](http://www.yelp.com/biz/dallas-marketing-rockstar-dallas?adjust_creative=3cZu3ieq3omptvF-Yfj2ow&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=3cZu3ieq3omptvF-Yfj2ow%27)

My code:

```
def get_websites():

    for yso in Company.objects.filter(crawled=False, source='YAG'):
        r = requests.get(yso.url)
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        if soup.select_one(".g-recaptcha") != None:
            sys.exit("Captcha")
        soup_select = soup.select_one("a[href*='biz_redir']")
        try:
            yso.website = soup_select.text
            print('website for %s added' % (yso.website))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('no website for %s added' % yso.name)

        if not yso.crawled:
            yso.crawled = True
            yso.save()
```

Using `lxml` and `html.parser` with the CSS Selector `soup.select_one("a[href*='biz_redir']")` returns `None`, also `soup.select("a[href*='biz_redir']")` being an empty list, and `soup.find_all("a[href*='biz_redir']")` being an empty list.

```
lxml version 4.5.0

beautifulsoup version 4.9.3
```

Edit: Changing `"a[href*='biz_redir']"` to just `a` results in the same thing. There is something more fundamentally wrong than syntax, if syntax is even wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically, so `requests` doesn't support it. However, the link is loaded via JSON format on the website, you can extract using the `json` module.

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/dallas-marketing-rockstar-dallas?adjust_creative=3cZu3ieq3omptvF-Yfj2ow&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=3cZu3ieq3omptvF-Yfj2ow%27"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

script = soup.select_one(
    "#wrap > div.main-content-wrap.main-content-wrap--full > yelp-react-root > script"
).string

json_data = json.loads(re.search(r"({.*})", script).group(1))

print(
    "https://yelp.com"
    + json_data["bizDetailsPageProps"]["bizContactInfoProps"]["businessWebsite"]["href"]
)
```

---

An alternative would be to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to scrape the page, which supports dynamic content

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/dallas-marketing-rockstar-dallas?adjust_creative=3cZu3ieq3omptvF-Yfj2ow&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=3cZu3ieq3omptvF-Yfj2ow%27"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
# Wait for the page to fully render
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
print("https://yelp.com" + soup.select_one("a[href*='biz_redir']")["href"])

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://yelp.com/biz_redir?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rockstar.marketing&website_link_type=website&src_bizid=CodEpKvY8ZM7IbCEWxpQ0g&cachebuster=1607826143&s=d214a1df7e2d21ba53939356ac6679631a458ec0360f6cb2c4699ee800d84520
```